# Swap colour in alluvian plot

Tags: r, plot, colors

I created an alluvian plot (image below) and would like to just swap the colours so unresolved is red and solved green, but cannot mannage to do that. Already tried also changing the dataframe, it doesn't make a diference.

I used the script:

```
ggplot(data = D180_PROPOSAL1,
       aes(axis1 = Data, axis2 = Issue,
           y = Frequency)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Data", "Issue"), expand = c(.05, .1)) +
  xlab("Assesment at Day 180") +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Unresolved)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Uncertainties in the evaluation of bevacizumab biosimilars",
          "stratified by type of data and type of issue")
```

[Here is the picture of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niuUY.png)

I also included the dataset in a link [Dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rIYRigou_Njlk5wdxf2OE0tZhAy3SRdC/edit#gid=108357883)

Comment: One way of doing this is by using the  `scale_fill_manual()` function that allows you to define the colors of the alluviums with the `values` parameters. You could write `scale_fill_manual(values = c("Solved" = "#7CAE00", "Unresolved" = "#F8766D"))` where `"#7CAE00"` is the default "green" and "#F8766D" is the default "red".

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried but it doesn't work.. is it maybe because I have to put in a specific part of the script?

Comment: The `scale_fill_manual()` is a ggplot layer. So you can add a line within the chuck of code building the figure (starting with ggplot) containing the proposed solution.

Comment: In order for us to help us, we would need to be able to replicate your code. For this we would need the "D180_PROPOSAL1" data.

Comment: HI! Thank you! I included the dataset in a hyperlink above

Answer (score 0):

Below you may find a solution to your problem.

What i did is to use the `scale_fill_manual()` layer function with parameter `values = c("Solved" = "#7CAE00", "Unresolved" = "#F8766D")`. This will color the alluvium belonging to "Solved" into the default green color ("#7CAE00") and the alluvium belonging to "Unresolved" into the default red color ("#F8766D").

```
library(readxl)
library(ggalluvial)

# Load the data: 
D180_PROPOSAL1 <- readxl::read_excel(path = "D180_PROPOSAL1.xlsx")

# Plot the original figure
p <- ggplot(data = D180_PROPOSAL1,
       aes(axis1 = Data, axis2 = Issue,
           y = Frequency)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Data", "Issue"), expand = c(.05, .1)) +
  xlab("Assesment at Day 180") +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Unresolved)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Uncertainties in the evaluation of bevacizumab biosimilars",
          "stratified by type of data and type of issue")

# modify the colors of the alluvium: 
# #7CAE00 = default green
# #F8766D = default red
p <- p +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Solved" = "#7CAE00", "Unresolved" = "#F8766D"))

plot(p)
```

The resulting figure is:

[image: Alluvial_plot_example_1]